# What could cause activerecord sum to return the wrong value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am getting an odd result from an activerecord query, and I cannot figure out why.

```
parent.children
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation[#<Child id: 1, date: "2018-01-01", quantity: 10>]>

parent.children.size
=> 1

parent.children.group(:date).count
=> {Mon, 01 Jan 2018=>1}

parent.children.group(:date).sum(:quantity)
=> {Mon, 01 Jan 2018=>20}
```

What could cause `sum` to return `20`?

As you can see, there is only one record, and the value being summed is `10`. `sum` should return `10`.

In fact, calling the Child model directly returns the correct result.

```
Child(:date).sum(:quantity)
=> {Mon, 01 Jan 2018=>10}
```

Even more confusing, this particular method is in a concern that is shared between several models. Elsewhere it calculates the correct sum. Only one model is returning this odd result.

Scratching my head how to debug this, it really doesn't seem to make sense. How is it possible for `sum` to return a value greater than expected?

Comment: I would experiment in your DB if I were you.

Comment: Thanks @MarekLipka. experiment how?

Comment: Well first of all, check what SQL query is being generated by your code (the one that works weird). Then copy this query into DB console and check what happens.

Comment: BTW it seems the `group` clause break something. So you can start experimenting on the result of `parent.children.group(:date).to_sql`.